# Terminal can open module plotly but IDLE can't

Tags: python-2.7, terminal, plotly, python-idle

I pip installed plotly, a module for graphing on python. When I access it from the terminal, it imports and works perfectly fine. However, if I try and access it from IDLE, the following error keeps being thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1
    from plotly import plotly
  File 
 "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/plotly/__init__.py", line 31
from plotly import (plotly, dashboard_objs, graph_objs, grid_objs, 
tools,
  File 
 "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/plotly/plotly/__init__.py", line 10
from . plotly import (
  File 
 "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-
 packages/plotly/plotly/plotly.py", line 28
     from requests.compat import json as _json
   File 
 "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-
 packages/requests/__init__.py", line 97
    from . import utils
   File 
 "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-
 packages/requests/utils.py", line 24
from . import certs
   File 
 "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-
 packages/requests/certs.py", line 15
     from certifi import where
ImportError: No module named certifi
```

Comment: Do you get the same error when you import requests?
Which OS are you on?

Comment: I'm on MacOS, and yeah same error: no module named certifi

Comment: In that case, it looks like a problem with `requests` and not `plotly`, try reinstalling it and have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943536/pyinstaller-no-module-named-certifi-error